# Can I set the MTU to be 9000 for everything on my network except the internet router?

Tags: networking

I need to set the MTU to 9000 for my network devices, except for the BT Home Hub which is limited and cannot be configured.

9000 means I get 50MB/s instead of 11MB/s between the server and the NAS.
But it means that certain sites fail when browsing the internet.

Is it possible to set the machine to speak 9000 to everything *except* the router?

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to ask him to change the MTU for specific devices, maybe if you use two cards it could be possible.

I am not at 100% certain. But what I am certain is that you are suppose to use 9600 MTU and usually that's the way the other devices in your home is suppose to work at.

Comment: Yeah, _supposed to_, but BT puts a gigabit port on their switch which defaults to 1500 and can't be configured... ¬.¬